# Any way to have a method that create new instances of a class passed by parameter?

Tags: java

I am creating tests in which I have to create lists to send to the object under test. In order to create the lists, I would like to have a method called `createEntitiesList`, in which I send the number of elements in the list and receive the list filled with elements (with valid, but random generated values).
That is very basic, but I would like to be able to create lists of different types, for instance

```
List<Professor> list = createEntityList(Professor.class);
List<Student> list = createEntityList(Student.class);
```

Of course Professor and students have different attributes I would like to fill out.

My current method is this one:

```
    private <T> List<T> getEntityList(Class<T> entityType, int numberOfItems) {
        List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            if (entityType.equals(ProfessorEntity.class)) {
                entities.add((T) createProfessorEntity(i));
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
            }

        }

        return entities;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T> T createProfessorEntity(int index) {
        ProfessorEntity entity = new ProfessorEntity();
        entity.setTitle(String.format("Title %s", index));
        entity.setNamecompany);
        return (T) entity;
    }
```

Ok, it works, but I feel I didn't really achieved my goal, because I would have to create a new method and an "if" statement for each new type of class I want to create.
On the other side, I do not see any improvements I could make to required less effort.

Is there any way I can improve this code to be able to call only one method that will create entities of the desired type but reduce the effort to add a new supported class?

ps: the effort is not so big, but I would like to learn because it could be useful in the future.

Comment: Try with Reflection API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Start by defining an interface:

```
public interface EntityCreator<T> {
    T create(int index);
}
```

And then pass an instance of this interface to your method:

```
private <T> List<T> getEntityList(EntityCreator<T> creator, int numberOfItems) {
    List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        entities.add(creator.create(i));
    }

    return entities;
}
```

Then, to create 10 professor entities:

```
List<ProfessorEntity> list = getEntityList(this::createProfessorEntity, 10);
```

If you're not under Java 8 yet, you'll have to use inner classes:

```
List<ProfessorEntity> list = getEntityList(new EntityCreator<ProfessorEntity>() {
    @Override
    public ProfessorEntity create(int index) {
        return createProfessorEntity(i);
    }
}, 10);
```

Comment: You solution looks clean and tidy. But as I understand OP also wants to get rid of methods like createProfessorEntity(). Or did I understand it wrong?

Comment: He can of course inline the method call inside the lambda or anonymous class.

Comment: Your solution is really elegant :) But I really think I won't be able to escape some EntityCreator method, if I want to populate the instance information, right? (for instance professor.setName())

Comment: Unless all the entities extend the same class or implement the same interface, and you can thus use the same code to populate them all, then no.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you can do:

But remember to add default constructors to all the classes that you want to be instantiated. This solution makes use of reflection API and invokes default constructors of these classes to instantiate them.

```
private <T> List<T> getEntityList(Class<T> entityType, int numberOfItems) throws Exception {
    List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        Constructor<T> ctor = entityType.getConstructor();
        entities.add(ctor.newInstance());
    }

    return entities;
}
```

If you have control over the classes that you want to instantiate this way, one thing you can do to improve them is to use a super-class or interface that all these classes inherit from. This way you can add type-safety to the method:

```
private <T extends Instantiable> List<T> getEntityList(Class<T> entityType, int numberOfItems) throws Exception {
    List<T> entities = new ArrayList<T>();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        Constructor<T> ctor = entityType.getConstructor();
        entities.add(ctor.newInstance());
    }

    return entities;
}
```

This helps you to get rid of the exception that you were throwing and this only allows the supported classes to be instantiated.

And yes, remember to hadle the exceptions properly.

Comment: That is a great solution, I was able to get this far, but I was stuck on the following problem: how do I fill the values of the instance? (for instance professor.setName()

Comment: In this solution, the only place you have to set these values is default constructor.

Comment: you mean I would have a constructor public MyEntity(String name) for instance=

Comment: Nope. You can't have that in this solution. The only way to set these values would be to override default  constructor. So you'll have to write a constructor that does not take any parameter and then you can set the values there. e.g. public MyEntity() {this.name="ABC";}

Comment: How do you get a `Class<T>` instance? I only seem to be getting `Class<?>`, it's odd.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: what do you mean?